# Disable textbox if other textbox is not empty in CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search form which contains text-boxes. What I want to ask is if `textbox1(Hotel (num_rooms))` is not empty then the `textbox2(Packages(num_days))` will be disabled or if `textbox2(Packages(num_days))` is not empty then the `textbox1(Hotel (num_rooms))` will be disabled. Because this search form will leads to different output based on the inputs of an user. If the user tries to put data in `textbox1` and submit it, then it will return a lot of recommendations based on the user preferences about hotel same as in packages.

```html
<form action="Filtered-SearchResult.php" method="post">
  <div class="SearchForm">
<label id="Form"><h3 style="color:beige; text-align:left;">Search Form</h3></label><br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="location" class="searchtext" id="locate" placeholder="location" onkeyup="LettersOnly(this)" /><br>
<input type="text" name="from_budget" class="searchtext" placeholder="minimum budget" style="width:150px;" onkeyup="NumbersOnly(this)" />
<input type="text" name="to_budget" class="searchtext" placeholder="maximum budget" style="width:150px;" onkeyup="NumbersOnly(this)" /><br>
<input type="text" name="person" class="searchtext" placeholder="no of person" onkeyup="NumbersOnly(this)" /><br>
<input type="text" name="no_of_rooms" class="searchtext" style="width:150px;" placeholder="hotel(num_rooms)" onkeyup="NumbersOnly(this)" />
<input type="text" name="no_of_days" class="searchtext" style="width:150px;" placeholder="Packages(num_days)" onkeyup="NumbersOnly(this)" />
<script>
  function LettersOnly(input) {
    var regex = /[^a-zA-Z ]/gi;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
  }

  function NumbersOnly(input) {
    var regex1 = /[^0-9]/gi;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex1, "");
  }
</script>
<input type="submit" name="search1" value="Show Prices" id="Prices2" />
  </div>
</form>
```

[image: Search Form Picture(Sample Output)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a change event for no of rooms and no of days like this.
You can add more condition accordingly

```
$("#no_of_days").change(function(){

    if($(this).val() == ""){
        $("#no_of_rooms").attr("disabled", false);
    }else{
        $("#no_of_rooms").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });

  $("#no_of_rooms").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
        $("#no_of_days").attr("disabled", false);
    }else{
        $("#no_of_days").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` or why not simply `this.value`? `==` why type conversion? It's needed? Also you could convert your 5 lines of `if... else` to `$("#no_of_rooms").prop("disabled", !this.value);` making 10 lines just two. Than some elements caching would be fine too...